# Can I put script commands in one line?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

Do I have to place script commands for .ahk file in new line each, or I can just put them in one line?

So instead of having

```
Send, {F9}
Sleep,  1000
Send, {F9}
Sleep,  1000
```

Can I have

```
Send, {F9} Sleep,  1000 Send, {F9} Sleep,  1000
```

?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: As far as I know only functions can be joined together with a comma, not commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one command per line